# Inviscid Shallow Water Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

Aside from wikipedia where might I find a fairly comprehensive, yet simple to read, piece of literature on the inviscid shallow water equation?  Can you recommend any texts?  I don't want literature covering hilbert spaces, or anything too abstract just something that will give me the jist of the necessary concepts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book from C. B. Vreugdenhi called Numerical Methods for Shallow-Water Flow. It includes a derivation starting from the standard Navier Stokes Equations and later discusses other topics such as boundary conditions or comparison with compressible euler equations.

I don't think that there is any functional analysis in there...